# How to format SQL date timestamp from Bigint to C# date

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, bigint

I need to convert dates in an SQL view from BIGINT value (format: *20220504112601755*) to C# date time value (to some similar format: ***2022.05.04 11:26:01***) within C#.

All I found were unix epoch times and how to convert those to readable date times but not much about my issue.

Any help would be appreciated. (Didn't include any code because nothing I tried even came close to working as I wanted)

Thanks

Comment: Ugh, that's a horrible way of storing dates in the database. If possible, fix that and store dates as... dates! Otherwise, you will have to parse this manually. for example, you can convert to a string and split it up.

Comment: It's automatically stored this way by another program which I cannot control so I have to work with what I have. I thought about splitting strings but I was hoping for something more simple if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `DateTime` `ParseExact` method e.g.:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("20220504112601755", "yyyyMMddhhmmssfff", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: tried this but getting System.FormatException on the string

Comment: edit: adding an extra 'f' solved it and it is usable. If there's no other way then I'll use this.

Comment: Sorry, I missed out an f. I've updated the answer